# Took a practice technical interview online,,, what am I missing?

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I am preparing for interviewing for jobs soon, and took a practice technical test. I did pretty well on the problems, except for this one...

The premise of the problem is this: Given an array, find the maximum difference for sequential subsets of the array of size "n". Example

```
input = [6,8,4,5,3,1,7], n=3
[6,8,4] = the biggest diff = 4 (8-4)
[8,4,5] = the biggest diff = 4 (8-4)
[4,5,3] = 2
[5,3,1] = 4
[3,1,7] = 6
Final return from function:6
```

The limits of inputs were something like :the length of array will be less than 100k, n will be less than the length of array. **The function must finish within 2 seconds.**

I initially wrote this in python, but only received 3/6 correct test cases, 3 failed due to time limits, so I rewrote in C hoping for better performance.

```
int i,j;
int maxdiff = 0;
int localmax,localmin,localdiff;
for (i=0;i<v_length-d+1;i++){
    localmax = v[i];
    localmin = v[i];
    localdiff = 0;
    for(j=0;j<d;j++){
        if(v[j+i] > localmax){
            localmax = v[j+i];
        }
        if(v[j+i] < localmin){
            localmin = v[j+i];
        }
    }
    localdiff = localmax-localmin;
    if(localdiff > maxdiff){
        maxdiff = localdiff;
    }
}
return maxdiff;
```

I tried running this, but to the same results. 3/6 correct, 3/6 failed due to runtime.

Am I missing something here? I realize that I loop over each value in the array ArraySize-n times, I can somehow visualize in my mind that it is possible to loop through the array only once, but cannot seem to figure out how.
Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can do this in O(nlogn) using one min heap and one max heap for the subset.
during traversing the array remove fist element from heaps and add new element

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve questions involving sequential subsequences of a long input sequence is to use a (single-ended) queue, at least conceptually. (In the case where the input is a vector, rather than a stream, it's not actually necessary to store the queue, but the algorithm is often clearer if the queue is made explicit.)

In this case, the solution requires finding the largest difference between the max and the min of the queue. If we want an `O(1)` solution, we need a queue for which the operations `push_back`, `pop_front`, `min` and `max` are all `O(1)`.

The first thing to note is that if we were looking for a *stack* with that property (where `pop_front` is replaced with `pop_back`), the solution is trivial: whenever we push a new value, we compute the new min and max, and push them along with the new value. When we pop a value, we also pop the associated min and max, and the min and max remaining on the top of the stack are again correct.

How do we translate that to a queue? The answer is that we need to implement the queue using a stack. Or more accurately, using two stacks. This is the so-called "banker's queue", which provides an amortized `O(1)` (functional) queue using two (functional) stacks.

It's a simple trick: one of the stacks -- the front stack -- is used for pushing, and the other stack -- the back stack -- is used for popping. The front of the queue is kept in the front stack, and the back of the queue is kept in reverse order on the back stack, so that the top of the back stack is the first element in the queue. This works fine until the back stack is empty and we need to pop the first element. At that point, we simply pop the elements from the front stack one at a time, and push each one onto the back stack. Once we've done that, the front stack is empty, and the top of the back stack is what was the last element in the front stack, which was the first element of the queue, as desired.

It's clear that the above implementation is amortized `O(1)` because every element is pushed once onto each stack (and popped once from each stack). It's not actually `O(1)` on each operation, of course: every once in a while a `pop_front` will take quite a long time. But the average always works out right. (Pushes, on the other hand, are always `O(1)`.)

So we can make a min-max queue out of two min-max stacks, and the use that to solve the maximum range problem.

With that outline, it's easy to find some optimizations. First, we can store both stacks in the same array, and if we store the back stack backwards and contiguous with the front stack, then we only need to keep track of the position of the boundary between the two stacks, and the operation of popping the front stack and pushing that value onto the back stack consists of simply moving the boundary pointer. (In the case of min-max stacks, we need to compute the mins and maxes, though.) That leads to a simple circular buffer implementation, which is a common queue solution.

Furthermore, in the case of a moving window, the size of the queue is known, so we don't have to deal with dynamic resizing. And, in the case that the input is a vector, we don't need to actually push elements onto the front stack, since the elements are at a known place in the input and we don't need the stack min/max values in the front stack.

I hope all that is sufficient to explain this C++ implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::min;
using std::max;

struct minmax { int min; int max; };

int maxrange(const std::vector<int>& v, int n) {
  int sz = v.size();
  n = min(n, sz);
  if (n <= 1) return 0;
  // The stack only needs n - 2 elements. So this could be adjusted.
  minmax* stack = new minmax[n];
  int loback, hiback, lofront, hifront;
  int maxrange = 0;
  for (int s = n - 1, m = 0; s < sz; ++s, --m) {
    if (m == 0) {
      lofront = hifront = v[s];
      loback = hiback = v[s - 1];
      for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        stack[i - 2] = minmax{loback, hiback};
        loback = min(loback, v[s - i]);
        hiback = max(hiback, v[s - i]);
      }
      m = n - 1;
    } else {
      lofront = min(lofront, v[s]);
      hifront = max(hifront, v[s]);
      loback = stack[m-1].min;
      hiback = stack[m-1].max;
    }
    maxrange = max(maxrange, max(hifront, hiback) - min(lofront, loback));
  }
  delete[] stack;
  return maxrange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
int inp[]={...},n=...;
```

1. create int index array for the input

   ```
   const int N=sizeof(inp)/sizeof(inp[0]);
   int ix[N];
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++) ix[i]=i;
   ```
2. index sort `inp[N]` in `ix[N]` ascending (keep `inp[N]` unchanged)

   - so for any `i={0,1,2,...,N-2}` is `(inp[ix[i]]<=inp[ix[i+1]])==true`
   - this can be done in `O(N*log(N))`
3. now any subset of size `1<n<=N` starting from `int i0=0,1,2,...N-n` is done like this:

   ```
   int i1=i0+n-1; // valid indexes for subset are i0<=i<=i1;
   int min=0,max=0;
   for (i=  0;i< N;i++) if ((ix[i]>=i0)&&(ix[i]<=i1)) { min=inp[ix[i]]; break; }
   for (i=N-1;i>=0;i--) if ((ix[i]>=i0)&&(ix[i]<=i1)) { max=inp[ix[i]]; break; }
   int diff=max-min;
   ```
4. cycle bullet 3 through all locations

   - and find the max diff ...

[notes]

- this is faster for bigger `n` but slower for smaller `n`
- so the best would be to use your approach and this according to n size treshold